# Python sqlalchemy query with quote in between

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use python to query oracle database with SQLAlchemy. I am able to get data with a normal query, but it always returns an empty DataFrame when the `where` clause contains quote signs, such as condition below: `A in ('a','b','c','d')`.

```
engine = create_engine(...)
query = '''select * from table where ( A in (:A_Value) and BIN (:B_Value))'''
df= pd.read_sql_query(query , con=engine, params = {"A_Value": A_value, "B_Value" : B_value})
```

`A_value` is the value of a dataframe. I tried to form a comma-separated string with quote as `A_value = " 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' "`

I am wondering where done wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters are interpreted as a single value and no row matches to `IN ("'a', 'b', ...")`.

What you have to do is to construct the `IN`-clause with the appropriate number of replacement-markers and then pass this number of parameters. For example `"IN (" + ','.join(['?']*len(A_Value)) + ")"`, which gives you `"IN (?, ?, ?)"` if `A_Value` has three values.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried to add ', '.join(['%s']*len(A_Value)) in, and flatten the params into tuple combined with B_value. Which give me error "an illegal variable name/number", seems like still need to pass a variable name to each value.